# QGIS classified raster - compare surrounding pixel classes

Tags: qgis

I have a classified raster where one class represents tree and around tree can be busches as another class and there is the third classes grass. I don't know how to analyse:

I have to compare the tree and busch surrounding class area (pixels)

1. if tree area is greater as busch area - is ok
2. if busch area is bigger as tree area - set for every pixel in tree area if surrounding 3x3pixels area has more trees/buschesand set this pixel by that either positive or negative value

Comment: Your first condition (tree area < bush area) is identical to the second condition (bush area > tree area).

Comment: Could you please a screenshot of the raster data you are working with? I’m your case, it looks like converting your classified raster to vector polygon may help with your analysis.